# как написать следующее выражение step === 4 или 5 ? null : <Component />

Tags: javascript, reactjs

step === **4 или 5** ? null :

спасибо

Comment: `[4,5].includes(step)`

Answer (score 0):

Для примера можно так:

```
const result = (step === 4 || step === 5) ? null : <Component />
```

Полезная ссылка: [Логические операторы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)